# .first() method of jquery not working in ie9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I need to select first ul from div as this div contains nested .I have html format like below

```
<div id="qcr">
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li></li>
        <li>
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and I used following script to select first  from div as it works in chrome and firefox and also in ie10 but not in ie9 and less

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#qcr ul").first().addClass("move");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using. Also what exactly does "not working" mean? Is `$("#qcr ul").first()` an empty collection? Is the class added to the wrong element? Do you get a runtime exception? Are clowns jumping all over your site?

Comment: Are you using jQuery 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: @Felix Kling i need to add class move to the first ul in div .its not working in ie9 and jQuery version is 1.9.1

Comment: @itsoftware but **how is it not working** Felix's questions were quite clear, add appropriate

Comment: What makes you think it's not working? The first `ul` is the one with `class="navbar"`. Is that the one you want to add the `move` class to?

Comment: `I need to select first ul from div` if you check the dev tools the first UL has the class move.The parent ul.

Comment: @Barmar . yes. I need to add class move to first ul with has class = "navbar"

Comment: [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ask5ew1y/) works in IE9.

Comment: @Barmar thanks . will check it once again in ie9 and less

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using first(),  use a child selector.

```
$("#qcr > ul")
```